# C program to produce pattern of digits

Tags: c

**In this program the number of digits are limited to 4 digits, and every time i want to add a digit i have to re-type previous "for loop + 1". How can i re-modify this program to make it for n number of digits? Or is there any better way to make it for a larger number of digits like 100 or 1000?**

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num=3,i,j,k,l;
//for one digit
    for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
//for two digit
    for(i=0;i<=num;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=num;j++)
            printf("%d%d\n",i,j);
    }
//for three digits
    for(i=0;i<=num;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=num;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<=num;k++)
                printf("%d%d%d\n",i,j,k);
        }
    }
//for four digits
    for(l=0;l<=num;l++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<=num;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<=num;j++)
            {
                for(k=0;k<=num;k++)
                    printf("%d%d%d%d\n",l,i,j,k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0
1
2
3
00
01
02
03
10
11
...
...
3331
3332
3333
```

Comment: One starting place is to figure out how many digits are in your target number.  In the case above you are working with integers so how can you calculate the number of digits (base 10) there are in your number?  Once you know that, you will know the number of loops you need.  Once you know the number of loops you need, check out the concept of "recursion".  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is sample app which can display any amount of digits with any maximal digits (up to 9)

```
#include <stdio.h>

// maximal value of single digit to display
#define NUM 3
// maximal count of digits to display
#define DIGITS 3

void printDigit(char* digits, int offset) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= NUM; i++) {
        digits[offset] = '0' + i; // set single digit
        if ((offset + 1) < DIGITS) {
            // we need to display more digits
            printDigit(digits, offset + 1);
        } else {
            // it was last digit in number, display whole number
            printf("%s\n", digits);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char digits[DIGITS + 1] = {0};
    for (int i = 1; i <= DIGITS; i++) {
        printDigit(digits, 0);
    }
}
```

it uses recursion to set digits from left to right in variable digits

Answer (score 1):

Think about recursion. If you have n digits, then recur your function n times according to this relation:

```
f(n):
     if(n == 0) break;
     for(i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
         i + f(n - 1);
     }
```

That's all I think.